# Shall I keep windows and blinds open during hot summer days?

Tags: windows, cooling, blinds

On a summer day with at 36 degrees Celsius, in a room with no air conditioner but only a ceiling fan, and with windows facing north and east, which of the following can I do to make the room feel less hot:

- open or close windows
- pull down or up the blinds on the windows

I guess that both heat and some wind (although not cool air) can come in through the windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried some experiments to see what works best for you? It should only take 4 days to try all 4 of your possibilities...

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. There are too many factors involved. You'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Freeman's comment is exactly right.  The optimum approach depends on delta temperature, humidity, breezes, how long the sun shines directly into a window, etc.

Get a couple thermometers (and humidity monitors if you can) and record the variation from dawn to dusk for several days with windows closed, several with windows open, etc.

If your area cools down nicely at night, then be sure to keep windows open all night, then close them up in the AM to preserve the cool air in the room, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer consists of two parts: one is avoiding solar heat gain so that the room actually *is* cooler, and the other part is controlling the air so that the room *feels* cooler.

### Solar Gain

This depends on where on the planet you're located (ie which latitude/hemisphere) and on the exterior features of the building and site (ie roof overhangs, trees, neighboring buildings).

In the middle-latitude northern hemisphere which I'm familiar with, at the peak of summer, there are a few hours in the early morning and late evening when the sun goes far enough north in the sky that it could shine in through a north-facing window. Covering that window during those hours with blinds, or especially with something on the exterior of the glass, can make a little reduction in solar heat gain.

If the east-facing window is not somehow shaded during the morning hours it'll bring in a tremendous amount of solar heat gain and that'll stay in the room for the rest of the day. Again, shading the window with blinds or something on the exterior can help a lot.

The same principles would apply closer to the equator or in the southern hemisphere.

### Room Air

We humans cool ourselves partly by radiating heat and partly by perspiring (evaporation). Evaporation is enhanced by moving air; that's why the fan helps. A breeze coming through the windows *might* help -- for example, if human occupancy in the room has caused its relative humidity to rise higher than the humidity outdoors, then having the windows open would help. If the difference is extreme then it might make sense to open the windows *even if the outdoor air temperature is higher than the indoor temperature*.

### Other stuff

The "right thing" to do with the blinds and the windows may change hour to hour and day to day. You'll need to make yourself aware of the movements of the sun through the day and of the changing outdoor humidity to make the best choices, and adjustments will be needed throughout the day. For example, open the windows overnight to let the structure be cooled by the evening breeze, close them up early in the morning to delay entry of hot outdoor air, and open them in the afternoon on days when it makes sense to do so.

Don't overlook the room finish and insulation. If the room has no interior finish and no insulation -- it is enclosed only by the exterior wall materials -- then solar heating of the exterior side of the wall will cause heat to be radiated into the room. That'll make the room feel hot no matter how much open-window breeze or ceiling fan or window covering action you have going on. If you feel heat radiating onto you upon entering the room, figure out a way to block that radiant heat.